# Why does std::thread wait in its constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lock-free, visual-c++-2015

The current implementation of the STL in Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 seems to disallow any lock-free environment to start a thread due to a mutex wait in the constructor.

```
void _Launch(_Thrd_t *_Thr)
    {   // launch a thread
    _Thrd_startX(_Thr, _Call_func, this);
    while (!_Started)
        _Cnd_waitX(_Cond, _Mtx); // <-- Why?
    }

template<class _Target> inline
    void _Launch(_Thrd_t *_Thr, _Target&& _Tg)
    {   // launch a new thread
    _LaunchPad<_Target> _Launcher(_STD forward<_Target>(_Tg));
    _Launcher._Launch(_Thr);
    }

explicit thread(_Fn&& _Fx, _Args&&... _Ax)
    {   // construct with _Fx(_Ax...)
    _Launch(&_Thr,
        _STD make_unique<tuple<decay_t<_Fn>, decay_t<_Args>...> >(
            _STD forward<_Fn>(_Fx), _STD forward<_Args>(_Ax)...));
    }
```

Can anybody tell me why this wait is needed?

I'm asking, because I currently examine a system that sometimes needs over 500ms to construct a `std::thread` but never shows this delay with using [`CreateThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: You want a lock-free thread start? Not going to happen... it's not just the C++ lib part.

Comment: Somehow, the fact that a heap allocation (by way of `make_unique`) is involved doesn't seem to bother you. Heap allocation is generally not lock-free.

Comment: also dont forget about the loader lock which must be acquired by system before your function gets executed.

Comment: `sometimes needs over 500ms to construct a std::thread` - looks like ctor of std::thread is waiting for system to start executing thread function body.

Answer (score 3):

```
_LaunchPad<_Target> _Launcher(_STD forward<_Target>(_Tg));
```

`_Launcher` is on the stack and is passed to the new thread. Why? I don't know, but this makes it important that `_Launcher` not go out of scope until the new thread is done with it. The wait is likely there to guarantee this.

Comment: it's probably on the stack in order to prevent `bad_alloc` exception which `std::thread` constructor is not supposed to throw.